# which way can control the rotation most efficiently?

Tags: scripting, random, models, unity-game-engine, updates

Since a large number of models are random rotating, which way can control the rotation most efficiently? Is it to bind the scripts on each model with rotation in the update?

PS:We encounter some problems when using the untiy3d engine. We use the version: 3.5.0 and the Ellipsoid Particle Emitter of the Legacy Particles with ios target platform.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a prefab with the model and script is the most common and possibly most efficient way to populate your scene with many similar objects.

You can use `Update()` to control it, but you should use `FixedUpdate()` to deal with physics stuff.

You could also have a script - in another game object that would only be a container for this script - to instantiate those asset objects instead of drag & dropping each one, if the number of objects is big enough to compensate for the work.

Answer (score 0):

**Explain:**

Are Random models same in body texture and other attributes?

**If yes,**
  then can help you Instantiating  prefabs [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html) and you can help you can just drag and drop code of rotation on one enemy and prefabs can access it randomly or you can also by making rotation rate public.

It will all depend on your code logic afterwards.